# Listening for enable/disable state change

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

For my custom components, when they go from enabled to disabled or disabled to enabled, I want to trigger a custom event.
I can't find any related events in the livedocs.
Any clues please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIComponent` does dispatch an event of type `enabledChanged` from its `set enabled` method. Here is the source of that method:

```
public function set enabled(value:Boolean):void
{
    _enabled = value;

    // Need to flush the cached TextFormat
    // so it recalcs with the disabled color,
    cachedTextFormat = null;

    invalidateDisplayList();

    dispatchEvent(new Event("enabledChanged"));
}
```

You can listen to it using:

```
myComponent.addEventListener("enabledChanged", handleEnabledChanged);
```

Answer (score 1):

If they're custom components, and I'm assuming you're extending UIComponent (or a child class), why don't you just override the Enabled setter method, then dispatch a custom event within that?

Something like:

```
override public function set enabled(value:Boolean):void {
   super.enabled = value;
   dispatchEvent(new EnabledChangedEvent());
}
```